# How do I import data into a SQL Server with auto detect column data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a nicely formatted csv file with over 100 columns.  I tried using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, but it has no feature to auto-detect the appropriate type of each column, defaulting the type to varchar(50).  Is there an alternative method where I can load the csv into a table and have auto-detect?

Comment: [bcp Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)...[Different way to import the data](http://monox.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/168/Different-ways-of-importing-data-into-SQL-Server/)

Comment: Does bcp create the table on the fly?

Comment: *"Does bcp create the table on the fly?"*: **No**

Comment: Well, if the table needs to be created beforehand, then the data types have already been determined, which is what I'm trying to automate.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried exporting your data to csv and NOT OPENING the file then perform transfer. if you open the CSV file excel will convert those columns to varchar.